# is-selected class in flickity can't detected in javascript

Tags: javascript, flickity

I'm creating slider using flickity and what I'm trying to do is when slide is selected the background color of body change (each slide has a specific color.. the problem is (is-selected) class can't detected in JavaScript even though I clearly see it in console

[image: is-selected class shown in console]

html:

```
<div class="carousel" data-flickity='{ "wrapAround": true }'>
                <div class="carousel-cell" data-color="red">
                    <img class="pic" src="./img/1.jpeg" alt="">

                </div>
                <div class="carousel-cell" data-color="blue">
                    <img class="pic" src="./img/2.jpeg" alt=""

                </div>
                <div class="carousel-cell" data-color="green">
                    <img class="pic" src="./img/3.jpeg" alt="">
                </div>

            </div>
```

```
let cell = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel-cell");
cell.forEach((c) => {
 // console.log(c.dataset.color);
  if (c.classList.contains("is-selected")) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
});
```

how can I solve this?

Comment: With a super simple example, your script works fine, but I think we need some more context. When/how are you calling the posted code? What does your actual html look like?

Comment: I edited with html code... I'm using flickity library and it's adds (.is-selected)class to the active slide, I want to select this class in js and do whatever I want but it seems the I can't select it I don't know why

Comment: When/how is your code executed? I'm wondering if this is a timing issue, that when you call the code you posted, the class either hasn't been added yet or has been removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might tweak Flickity itself like I do in the snippet below, or if you'd like to keep it clean, you want to use [mutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

```js
const selectFn = [
  'var a = fizzyUIUtils;',
  (Flickity.prototype.select + '').substring(16).replace(/}$/, ';'),
  'document.body.style.backgroundColor = this.cells.find(c => c.element.classList.contains("is-selected")).element.dataset.color;'
].join('');
Flickity.prototype.select = new Function('t', 'e', 'i', selectFn);
```

```css
.carousel {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 10vh 0 0 10vw
}

.carousel-cell,
.pic {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.pic {
  object-fit: contain
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>



<div class="carousel" data-flickity='{ "wrapAround": true }'>
  <div class="carousel-cell" data-color="red">
    <img class="pic" src="https://picsum.photos/id/21/400/300" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-cell" data-color="blue">
    <img class="pic" src="https://picsum.photos/id/16/400/300" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-cell" data-color="green">
    <img class="pic" src="https://picsum.photos/id/28/400/300" alt="">
  </div>

</div>
```